# PrintDocument and StreamReader in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

I'm using a `PrintDocument` to set a network printer and paper source. I have a `Stream` to print.

In this case, only a blank page is printed (on good printer and tray), so how bind the `StreamReader` to the `PrintDocument` in MVC4 ? Stream is well populated.

```
public ActionResult ImprimerEtiquettes(int patientId, int venueId, string uf)
        {
            //do some business logic to have a Stream with parameters

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fStream))
            {
                var doc = new PrintDocument();
                doc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "\\\\imp-dsii\\PI91063";
                PaperSource ps = doc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources[2];
                doc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = ps;
                doc.PrintPage += doc_PrintPage;
                doc.Print();
            }

            return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        void doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: The [ms documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print(v=vs.110).aspx) gives an example of handling the `PrintPage` event. Note its doc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(doc_PrintPage);

Comment: As we have a Aspose licence, finally I use it instead of standard Microsoft PrintDocument. Thank for your help.